# Calling an activity from class PintService

Tags: android

I created a class that extends PrintService .

I use the system dialog to print , everything is fine I see the service in print.

In onPrintJobQueued method I have this :

```
@Override
protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {
 printJob.start();

    Log.d(TAG, "queued: " + printJob.getInfo());

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfWiever.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    String file = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/"+printJob.getDocument().getInfo().getName();
    i.putExtra("data", file);
    try {
        printJob.complete();
        Log.d(TAG, "queued: " + printJob.getInfo());
        startActivity(i);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I'm not getting any errors in both stackTrace and logcat.
It's just that the business doesn't open.

I've seen other answers but I'm confused, in some I've read that there is a need for an interface to communicate between service and activity.

Or am I getting my intent call wrong?

I state that my activity is not running it is the service that must call it and put it into execution.

my AndroidManifest :

```
<activity
    android:name="soget.com.it.bluetooth.sdk.PdfWiever"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="SogetServizioStampa">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"   android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:scheme="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"   android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:scheme="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"   android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"   android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"   android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service
    android:name="soget.com.it.bluetooth.sdk.PdfPrint"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.printservice.PrintService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Can you direct me for a solution?

Comment: Background services can't start activities anymore.  The best you can do is post a notification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is a lot of documentation can you give me a link to Android Developers on how to do it.